# Typescript Marionette UI object

Tags: typescript, marionette

I have tried implementing a Marionette `ItemView` in Typescript and wanted to use the UI object to simplify the calls to UI elements as [described in the Marionette documentation](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.1/marionette.itemview.html#organizing-ui-elements).

I made the following example to simplify it:

```
/// <reference path="scripts/typings/marionette/marionette.d.ts" />

interface settings {
    el: any
    template: Function
}

class myApp extends Marionette.ItemView<Backbone.Model> {
    constructor(options: settings) {
        super(options);
    }

    ui = {
        hello: '.hello'
    }

    events() {
        return {
            'click @ui.hello': 'heyWorld'
        }
    }

    heyWorld() {
        console.log("Hey heyWorld!!!!");
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    var app = new myApp({
        el: document.getElementById('content'),
        template: (data) => {
            return '<div class="hello"><p>Hej world - click me</p></div>';
        }
    });
    app.render();
};
```

Which returns **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hello' of undefined"**

If I change the UI object to the following it starts to work but it just seems a bit hacky way of getting it to work:

```
get ui() {
        return {
            hello: '.hello'
        }
    }

    set ui(value) { 
        // somehow marionette want to set this.ui to an empty object 
    }
```

Has anybody run into this issue before? Anybody got a good way of implementing Marionette UI object that avoids the awkward get/set UI code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution was quite simple. Just had to pass the ui object with the options object like:

```typescript
class myApp extends Marionette.ItemView<Backbone.Model> {
    constructor(options: Backbone.ViewOptions<Backbone.Model>) {
        this.ui = {
            hello: '.hello'
        }
        super(options);
    }

    events() {
        return {
            'click @ui.hello': 'heyWorld'
        }
    }

    heyWorld() {
        console.log("Hey heyWorld!!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did this break already? cause 'this' is not allowed before super() in ES6. which brings us back to the error in the beginning..

Comment: Try calling `super` as the thing in the constructor. If that doesn't work, then try integrating ui into the options being passed to super, e.g. `options.ui = { hello: '.hello' }; super(options);`